# Can I use always the last version of Typescript?

Tags: typescript, npm

As far as I know Typescript is backwards compatible. 
Could I always import the last version in my projects?

I.e.:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "*"
  },
```

Is it recommended? There are any negative implications?

Comment: [There was a request to use semantic versioning](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14116) (so that breaking changes occurred only during major versions), but it was declined. You can likely be sure that a build version change (2.1.2 to 2.1.3) will be backwards compatible, minor versions hold no such tentative promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the typescript team tries to keep the compiler as backward compatible as possible this is not a 100% guarantee.

There is a long list of [breaking changes](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Breaking-Changes) that could create problems when you upgrade.